# EF Migration - One database, two projects

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

We are using EF Code First with manual migration (AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;). The problem is that we need to share one database between two projects.

```
Project-A
---DbContext-A
---------Model1
---------Model2
---------Model3

Project-B
---DbContext-A
---------Model2
---------Model3
---------Model4
```

Some of the migration files are the same but some of them are different. For example: Project-B needs Model4 but Project-A doesn't..

Currently, If I update the database with one migration, DbContext will not work in other project.

What would be the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

My feeling is that this is working against the intentions with migrations. I think that you should break out the `DbContext`, the entities and the migrations to a separate assembly that is shared between the two projects.

If that's not an option, you have to disable the compatibility check with the model. The compatibility check is done as part of the `IDBInitializer.InitializeDatabase` implementation, which is responsible for calling `Database.CompatibleWithModel`, so writing your own custom DB Initializer that does nothing would get you past that step. This also means that you take over the responsibility of ensuring that the database is compatible with the model. EF can't help you any more.